# Socket I.o não atualiza automaticamente

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket, websocket

Olá, estou utilizando o Socket i.o e quando eu envio um POST /EnviaTemperatura, não está atualizando automaticamente no meu site. O que estou fazendo errado?

**Node.js**

```
app.post('/EnviaTemperatura', function(req, res){
    temperatura = req.body.temp;
    console.log(temperatura);
    res.send('Temperatura: ' + temperatura);
});

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    socket.emit('RecebTemp', temperatura);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
    <div class="huge"><span id="EnviaTemp">0</span> ºC</div>
    <div>Temperatura no Interior da casa</div>
</div>

<script>
    var socket = io();
        socket.on('RecebTemp', function (temperatura) { 
            document.getElementById("EnviaTemp").innerHTML = temperatura;
        });
</script>
```

No meu caso, ele só está atualizando quando eu do um Refresh na página. Porém eu não queria dar um refresh na página inteira, somente nesse DIV, visto que tenho outros elementos na tela que demoram um pouco para carregar.

O que poderia ser?

Comment: Do jeito que está o seu código atualmente, o emit não está sendo executado no momento que uma requisição POST é realizada. O emit tem que estar dentro da função do app.post. Claro que para isso, terá de adaptar seu código.

Comment: Deixarei uma resposta para complementar este comentário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu código node.js, mude para:

```
app.post('/EnviaTemperatura', function(req, res){
    temperatura = req.body.temp;
    io.sockets.emit("RecebTemp", temperatura);
    console.log(temperatura);
    res.send('Temperatura: ' + temperatura);
});
```

E remova este trecho inteiro:

```
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    socket.emit('RecebTemp', temperatura);
});
```

Comment: exatamente o que eu precisava!
Obrigado!